# Printing a character data type as integer data type

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char a[12];
    scanf("%s",a);
    int s=0;
    s=s+a[1];
    printf("%d",s);
}
example:
a=1234
output:50
```

This is a basic c program.When i try to print the value of s,it displays 50
but when i replace `a[1]` with `a[1]-'0'`,it displays the exact value of character present at the index`(output: 2)`.Any reason why is it happening ?

Comment: code of `'2'` is `50`. Also code of `'0'` is `48`. So `50` - `48` is `2`.

Comment: What do you expect/want it to print?

Comment: Got the question wrong..writing in mobile for stackoverflow is not recommened.

Comment: `scanf("%s",a);` --> `scanf("%11s",a);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets take a look what happened at run time.

```
s is initialized to 0

and a[] is scanned with "1234";
```

which is

```
a[0] = '1';
a[1] = '2';
a[2] = '3';
a[3] = '4';
```

first case

```
s=s+a[1]; // 0 + asci value of 2 which evaluates to 50
```

second case

```
s=s+a[1]-'0' //  0 + asci value of 2 i.e 50 - asci value of 0 i.e 48 = 2
```

[man -a ascii](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html)

Answer (score 1):

Character constant `'2'` in the ASCII table has code 50. So using the format specifier `%d`  the character is displayed as an integer that is its value 50 is displayed.

As for this expression

```
a[1] - '0'
```

then as it has been said `a[1]` that represents the character `'2'` stores the ASCII value `50`. The character `'0'` has the ASCII code `48`. So the difference yieds `2`.

Answer (score 0):

C specifies that the codes for characters `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, ...  `'9'` are sequential.
`'0' + 3` must equal `'3'`.
This applies for any character set: the common [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or others.

Subtraction from `'0'` yields the numeric difference.

```
printf("%d",'2' - '0'); // must print 2
```

> ... the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous. ...   C11dr §5.2.1 3